# Save 3d numpy array with high speed into the Disk

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, save

I have a numpy array of size (192,192,4000) I would like to write this in a fast way on the disk. I don't care about the format, I can convert it afterwards.

What I do write now is that I save it in csv format which takes long time:

```
for i in range(0,192):
        np.savetxt(foder+"/{}_{}.csv".format(filename,i), data[i] , "%i", delimiter=", ")
```

Which takes 20-25 seconds. I tried pandas DataFrame and Panel approaches found in stackoverflow questions already and numpy save. All of them seems to run without error but the folder is empty when I open it.

Any idea how to improve the speed?

Why code runs without error but nothing is saved, for example for numpy.save?!

Comment: There are two different questions in here. The first is about the best method for saving NumPy arrays to disk, which is trivial. The second, _Why code runs without error but nothing is saved, for example for numpy.save?!_, cannot possibly be answered with so little information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the fastest way to save a large array like the one you have is to save it as a binary file, which can be done by numpy's save command. For example, the following creates a 3D array filled with zeroes, writes the array to a file and then retrieves it:

```
a = numpy.zeros((192,192,4000))
numpy.save("mydata.npy",a)
b = numpy.load("mydata.npy")
```

Of course, the file "mydata.npy" should be there in the present directory after the save command.

Comment: I didn't specify in .npy while saving, I works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also reshape your array from `3D to 2D` before saving. See the following code for an example.

```
import numpy as gfg 


arr = gfg.random.rand(5, 4, 3) 

# reshaping the array from 3D 
# matrice to 2D matrice. 
arr_reshaped = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], -1) 

# saving reshaped array to file. 
gfg.savetxt("geekfile.txt", arr_reshaped) 

# retrieving data from file. 
loaded_arr = gfg.loadtxt("geekfile.txt") 

# This loadedArr is a 2D array, therefore 
# we need to convert it to the original 
# array shape.reshaping to get original 
# matrice with original shape. 
load_original_arr = loaded_arr.reshape( 
    loaded_arr.shape[0], loaded_arr.shape[1] // arr.shape[2], arr.shape[2]) 

# check the shapes: 
print("shape of arr: ", arr.shape) 
print("shape of load_original_arr: ", load_original_arr.shape) 

# check if both arrays are same or not: 
if (load_original_arr == arr).all(): 
    print("Yes, both the arrays are same") 
else: 
    print("No, both the arrays are not same")
```

Comment: Is saving a 2d array faster than a 3d array?